# Inequality related with log-concave distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Fix any $n$-dimensional unit vector $\mathbf v$.

Let $\mathbf x$ be a random vector following the $n$-dimensional standard normal distribution. It has been shown (Analysis of Perceptron-Based Active Learning - Dasgupta et al. COLT 2005) that
$$
\Pr \left[ \left\lvert \mathbf u \cdot \dfrac{\mathbf x}{\lVert \mathbf x \rVert_2} \right\rvert \leq \epsilon \right] \leq \epsilon\sqrt{n}
$$
for any $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$.

If $\mathbf x$, instead, follows an isotropic (zero mean, identity covariance) log-concave distribution, it can be shown (using concentration properties of isotropic log-concave distributions from "The Geometry of Logconcave Functions
and Sampling Algorithms" - Lovasz, Vempala) that there exists some absolute constant $c > 0$ such that the weaker bound
$$
\Pr \left[ \left\lvert \mathbf u \cdot \dfrac{\mathbf x}{\lVert \mathbf x \rVert_2} \right\rvert \leq \epsilon \right] \leq c\epsilon \ln\left(1/\epsilon\right)\sqrt{n}
$$
holds for any $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$.

> Is there any known result/way to prove a $O(\epsilon \sqrt{n})$ upper bound in the isotropic log-concave case as well, namely get rid of the $\ln\left(1/\epsilon\right)$ factor?

Comment: Can you give a reference to your "it can be shown"?